# How to set Python Path in Unix?

Tags: python-2.7, installation

I am having Unix machine. I have to install python 2.7.14.
I downloaded python 2.7.14 from official website in the following directory.

```
/home/vivek/
```

Now I went inside the python directory and have done the following step.

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Everything was Ok.

But When I am checking the python version I get this.

```
Python 2.6
```

How to fix it. Can anyone please help?

Comment: why not just use `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: I don't have internet connectivity in my Unix.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an alias named python with the path:

## for example:

alias python "write the path to python version"

```
 alias python2.7 "/usr/local/bin/python"
 alias python3.6 "/home/vivek/python_dir/python"
```

this way you can write python2.7 to activate 2.7 ver
this way you can write python3.6 to activate 3.6 ver
and so on

you can also name alias as python
i find it easier to follow what i'm doing with labeling the version in the alias name .

Comment: you can also add the path to the $PATH env. but ... not advising this solution